# Programmatically add simple product for configuration product?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

In magento 2 I had created 3 product via my code. Product type is configurable, simple, simple.
so now don't know set two simple product into configuration product. 
thank for help!

Answer (score 0):

You can associate the simple products by loading the Configurable product.

Inject the below Class to Construct Method
\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,

So, $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;

Assuming the id of the configurable product as '3' and the simple as ,'1' and '2' respectively.

$associatedProductIds = [2,3];//Simple Product ids array

$configurableProduct = $this->_productRepository->getById(3);

$configurableProduct->setAssociatedProductIds($associatedProductIds);

$configurableProduct->save();

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank @richard-valsanlan. I tried you code. it not working.

Comment: Can you share your code ?